# how can i go back or UP one level Folder in document library web part in sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-part, document-library, folder, browsers

My question about document library web parts that appear in my first page in SharePoint 2010 Sites. (this picture )

[image: how to add button to up one level in document library web part]

when users want to browse in that web part **and when they click on folders** cant go up one level back!

how can i add button there to do this?

is there any hot key for this purpose?

what is your opinion or suggestions for solve this problem?

**// EDIT**

***up one level*** icon button on the ribbon in library tab. and users cant find it

Comment: If you were navigated to a folder from a link, this is no good, since back takes you... back. WE want to go UP, not BACK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the breadcrumb control (the folder on the top left in SP 2010) or the browsers back button is the approach. I have, though, written a custom list breadcrumb to be placed above or below a list view. But that will mean some custom coding (either a webpart, or by JavaScript in a content editor webpart)

Comment: up one level icon button on the ribbon in library tab. and users cant find it

Answer (score 1):

I did a simpler hack, putting a basic back button under the list, which is pretty good at calling up the folders after you have clicked into them. 
Go Back

```
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```